# Linear system with infinite number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false? A linear system with coefficient matrix $A$ has an infinite number of solutions iff $A$ can be row-reduced to an echelon matrix that includes some columns containing no pivots.

I think that the statement is false because take $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix and it can be row reduced to $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ but the system has no solution because $0\neq1$. Is my counterexample valid?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your question so my previous answer was inappropriate, your counterexample should be correct